# GWT and google app engine : restricted Java libraries

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, gwt

I'm having a bit of trouble with deploying an application to google app engine.

I've got the google plugin set up in eclipse. I want to deploy to the app engine but a few of the classes are not allowed by the GWT compiler. javax.mail.* for instance.

However the GAE docs (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/usingjavamail) seem to be perfectly happy with using javamail (And I'm pretty sure I had an application working with it deployed before).

What am I doing wrong?
Is there really no way to use these classes?!

Comment: Can you show us the code where you used mail? It should be on the server side only.

Comment: Ahh no I have it in the client package. So if I put it in the com.appspot.blabla.server package it will be ok? Is it a javascript conversion issue?

Comment: Please check this link: http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsCompatibility.html

Comment: JavaScript cannot send emails. Only the server can.

Comment: Yes I get it now. How silly of me.

Comment: But to solve your issue: the mail code should be on the server side, send the required parameters via rpc and execute in the backend not on the client side!

Comment: Ok now I have all my classes in the back-end. I don't actually need any user input for the page - however now I can't work out how to access those classes from the entrypoint. (Same problem!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On using [GWT](http://www.gwtproject.org/) you will code for two environment. The front-end (when the code will be translated to javascript) and the back-end that is a regular Servlet.

In the back-end you are free to use all jre/jdk API, for example, java-mail api. But in front-end you are limited to use classes describe in [JRE emulation](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html).

Check if your are not using a classes outside of [JRE Emulation](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html) in front-end (generally an `EntryPoint`) and try to move the code to back-end (your servlet).